# Event that fires after signature is added

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am writing an addin to change the signature of composed mails. I tried Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector. This does not work because at the time this is invoked the signature has not been added to the mail, but the mail Body is the mail Body of the original mail I am answering. 
How can I invoke my code after the signature has been added?

I did try

```
Private Sub inspectors_activate(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
```

and

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
```

both fire befor signature is added (I tested that by adding a MsgBox(mailItem.Body) in the Sub, there I can see that the Body is identically to the mail I am answering too.

EDIT
The activate - Event seems not to work - I tried:

```
    Public Sub inspector_activate(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector)_
       Handles inspector.activate
        Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
        Msgbox("test activate has fired")
        If Not TypeOf MailItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then Exit Sub
     end sub

Thanks
Max
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the Inspector.Activate event - it fires after the inspector is visible.

Comment: How exactly are you retrieving the message? Are you using Inspector.CurrentItem.Body?

Comment: i went for mailitem.body, now I also tried your suggestion, but this brings the same result.

Comment: Wait a second, your inspectors_activate() event handler above handles inspectors.NewInspector event, not Inspector.Activate!

Comment: thanks for your help! I have now tried  Private Sub inspector_activate() Handles inspector.Activate but that does not fire at all...

Comment: How do you declare and initialize the inspector variable?

Comment: Private WithEvents Inspector As Outlook.Inspector

Comment: And how exactly do you initialize that variable? Do you do that in your NewInspector event handler?